# Expected number of coin flips to get 3 consecutive occurences of either heads or tails?

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, puzzle

This question is taken from Mark Joshi's book "Quant Job Interview Questions And Answers".

**We play a game, with a fair coin. The game stops when either two heads (H) or tails (T) appear consecutively. What is the expected time until the game stops?**

I was able to solve this problem easily by writing a recurrence relationship. Mark also gives a solution that solves this problem by observing that once we know the 1st throw, the remaining coin tosses are exactly determined: [image]

However, a follow-up question in the book is **"How is the expectation changed if we alter the game so we need three consecutive occurrences of either heads or tails to end the game?"**

I am quite clueless on how to solve this follow-up. Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you generalize your method to three consecutives? What difficulty did you meet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in a comment, you could extend the given method.
However, here is a method without summing to infinity

With one toss, we get a streak of $1$ which may be either H or T. Call this state as  $a_1.$
We can write equations for *more* tosses  needed toss by toss now

$a_1 = 1 + 0.5*a_2 + 0.5*a_1\quad\quad[I]$
[With $0.5 Pr$ each, we either advance to streak $2$ or return to streak $1$]

$a_2 = 1 + 0.5*a_1\quad\quad[II]$
[Either we reach goal of $3$ streaks or fall back to $1$ streak]

Solving this give $a_1=6$, and adding the first toss gives the final answer as $7$

Comment: I see. That makes a lot of sense. Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome ! $\;\;$ :)